# Functional approach ~100 times slower than sequential in Kotlin?

Tags: performance, kotlin, functional-programming

So I picked up Project Euler again to play with Kotlin a bit. For those who do not know Project Euler is a site with programming exercises ranging from banal to pretty hard.

Anyway the very first problem is this:

If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

I solved this both sequentially and functionally since I wanted to see how they compared:

```
class ProjectEuler1 {
    companion object {

        fun sequential(): Int {
            var sum = 0
            for (i in 1..999)
                if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
                    sum += i
            return sum
        }

        fun functional(): Int = (1..999).filter { it % 3 == 0 || it % 5 == 0 } .sum()

        fun benchmark() {

            var solSequential = -1
            val tSequential = measureExactTimeMillis { solSequential = sequential() }

            var solFunctional = -1
            val tFunctional = measureExactTimeMillis { solFunctional = functional() }

            println("""
                +---
                |${this::class.java.canonicalName.replace(".Companion", "")}
                +---
                |Sequential solution: $solSequential
                |Sequential running time: ${tSequential.round(6)} ms
                +---
                |Functional solution: $solFunctional
                |Functional running time: ${tFunctional.round(6)} ms
                +---
            """.trimIndent())

        }
    }
}
```

`measureExactTimeMillis` is just `measureNanoTime` divided by `1_000_000` returning a `Double`.

Anyway, after running this several times the output was always more or less this:

```
+---
|ProjectEuler1
+---
|Sequential solution: 233168
|Sequential running time: 0.6097 ms
+---
|Functional solution: 233168
|Functional running time: 33.3555 ms
+---
```

The sequential, and sadly more verbose, version being 50-100x faster than the simple functional implementation.

What is the reason for this? Shouldn't the performances be at least comparable (as opposed to orders of magnitude apart)? Did I miss something that should have been done to optimize the functional implementation?

Comment: My guess as to why the functional version is slower: A combination of primitives being boxed/unboxed and the creation of an intermediate `List`.

Comment: @Slaw I thought kotlin functionals compiled similarly to Java streams which can do optimizations in the background such as lazy computations instead of eager collection after each step.

Comment: The extension functions provided for `Iterable` are eager and return intermediate iterables. The Kotlin equivalent, or at least near-equivalent, of Java streams is [sequences](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sequences.html).

Comment: @Slaw I found that too a few minutes ago but adding `.asSequence()` before the filter makes the operation take 10-20% longer.

Comment: Of course it's all about boxing/unboxing and extra collections. JVM does a lot of optimizations for operations with primitive types are does none for boxed types. In your sequential code you just do a simple `for`-loop with primitive `int` as iterator, and in your "functional" code you create a `List` of boxed `Integer`s and use an `Iterator` to iterate through it. Sequences can help you avoid extra collections, but they are generic, so boxing/unboxing will remain.